# GetItemLinqQueryable cosmos async call

Tags: .net, azure, nosql, azure-cosmosdb

We are planning to use Microsoft Azure Cosmos and calling a few of its APIs.

Does anybody know the usage of the `allowSynchronousQueryExecution` parameter while calling `GetItemLinqQueryable`?

Microsoft suggests that we should call `ToFeedIterator()` for async calls, so I was wondering, what is the use of the `allowSynchronousQueryExecution` parameter, if one doesn't call `ToFeedIterator()`?

Comment: Haven't found a clear explanation either. Have you found out?